# DC generating plant

Tags: power-supply, power, current, dc

What would happen if positive terminal of Dc get grounded in any DC generating plant?

Will it impact negative terminal and burn it?

Comment: Is the negative terminal earthed?

Comment: no..............

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "burn" we call that a **short circuit**, which means too much current flows and if that current is not interrupted (for example by a **fuse**) then the cables could get too hot, melt the insulation and cause fire etc.

So to cause problems, a **short circuit** can cause issues. Connecting the positive terminal to ground **by itself** does not cause a short circuit, only if the ground connection already has a connection to the negative terminal you get a short circuit. There will be no short circuit if the negative terminal is not connected to anything:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAB7HV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes it got short circuited some where but where  not getting the clue